# Databricks job getting javax.net.ssl.SSLHandshakeException: Received fatal alert: handshake_failure when calling api running in Google Cloud

Tags: rest, http, apache-spark, google-cloud-platform, databricks

A spark job running as a Databricks job tries to access an external rest api via http and the following error occurs: ERROR ScalaDriverLocal: User Code Stack Trace: 
javax.net.ssl.SSLHandshakeException: Received fatal alert: handshake_failure

Here is the code making the http call

```
Request request = new Request.Builder()
                .url("https://some_url")
                .get()
                .addHeader("cache-control", "no-cache")
                .build();

Response response = client.newCall(request).execute();
```

I have tried setting the https.protocols system variable in the code as follows

```
System.setProperty("https.protocols","TLSv1,TLSv1.1,TLSv1.2");
```

without results.

Here is the full stacktrace of the error:

```
ERROR ScalaDriverLocal: User Code Stack Trace: 
javax.net.ssl.SSLHandshakeException: Received fatal alert: handshake_failure
    at sun.security.ssl.Alerts.getSSLException(Alerts.java:192)
    at sun.security.ssl.Alerts.getSSLException(Alerts.java:154)
    at sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.recvAlert(SSLSocketImpl.java:2020)
    at sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.readRecord(SSLSocketImpl.java:1127)
    at sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.performInitialHandshake(SSLSocketImpl.java:1367)
    at sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.startHandshake(SSLSocketImpl.java:1395)
    at sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.startHandshake(SSLSocketImpl.java:1379)
    at okhttp3.internal.connection.RealConnection.connectTls(RealConnection.kt:351)
    at okhttp3.internal.connection.RealConnection.establishProtocol(RealConnection.kt:310)
    at okhttp3.internal.connection.RealConnection.connect(RealConnection.kt:178)
    at okhttp3.internal.connection.ExchangeFinder.findConnection(ExchangeFinder.kt:236)
    at okhttp3.internal.connection.ExchangeFinder.findHealthyConnection(ExchangeFinder.kt:109)
    at okhttp3.internal.connection.ExchangeFinder.find(ExchangeFinder.kt:77)
    at okhttp3.internal.connection.Transmitter.newExchange$okhttp(Transmitter.kt:162)
    at okhttp3.internal.connection.ConnectInterceptor.intercept(ConnectInterceptor.kt:35)
    at okhttp3.internal.http.RealInterceptorChain.proceed(RealInterceptorChain.kt:112)
    at okhttp3.internal.http.RealInterceptorChain.proceed(RealInterceptorChain.kt:87)
    at okhttp3.internal.cache.CacheInterceptor.intercept(CacheInterceptor.kt:82)
    at okhttp3.internal.http.RealInterceptorChain.proceed(RealInterceptorChain.kt:112)
    at okhttp3.internal.http.RealInterceptorChain.proceed(RealInterceptorChain.kt:87)
    at okhttp3.internal.http.BridgeInterceptor.intercept(BridgeInterceptor.kt:84)
    at okhttp3.internal.http.RealInterceptorChain.proceed(RealInterceptorChain.kt:112)
    at okhttp3.internal.http.RetryAndFollowUpInterceptor.intercept(RetryAndFollowUpInterceptor.kt:71)
    at okhttp3.internal.http.RealInterceptorChain.proceed(RealInterceptorChain.kt:112)
    at okhttp3.internal.http.RealInterceptorChain.proceed(RealInterceptorChain.kt:87)
    at okhttp3.RealCall.getResponseWithInterceptorChain(RealCall.kt:184)
    at okhttp3.RealCall.execute(RealCall.kt:66)
    at com.mycompany.metadata.MetadataRepository.loadAggregations(MetadataRepository.java:50)
    at com.mycompany.jobs.DefaultJob.run(DefaultJob.java:50)
    at com.mycompany.run.Main.main(Main.java:26)
    at line7ccb0b1a0bd6475aac11185531c9050025.$read$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw.<init>(command--1:1)
    at line7ccb0b1a0bd6475aac11185531c9050025.$read$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw.<init>(command--1:44)
    at line7ccb0b1a0bd6475aac11185531c9050025.$read$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw.<init>(command--1:46)
    at line7ccb0b1a0bd6475aac11185531c9050025.$read$$iw$$iw$$iw.<init>(command--1:48)
    at line7ccb0b1a0bd6475aac11185531c9050025.$read$$iw$$iw.<init>(command--1:50)
    at line7ccb0b1a0bd6475aac11185531c9050025.$read$$iw.<init>(command--1:52)
    at line7ccb0b1a0bd6475aac11185531c9050025.$read.<init>(command--1:54)
    at line7ccb0b1a0bd6475aac11185531c9050025.$read$.<init>(command--1:58)
    at line7ccb0b1a0bd6475aac11185531c9050025.$read$.<clinit>(command--1)
    at line7ccb0b1a0bd6475aac11185531c9050025.$eval$.$print$lzycompute(<notebook>:7)
    at line7ccb0b1a0bd6475aac11185531c9050025.$eval$.$print(<notebook>:6)
    at line7ccb0b1a0bd6475aac11185531c9050025.$eval.$print(<notebook>)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at scala.tools.nsc.interpreter.IMain$ReadEvalPrint.call(IMain.scala:793)
    at scala.tools.nsc.interpreter.IMain$Request.loadAndRun(IMain.scala:1054)
    at scala.tools.nsc.interpreter.IMain$WrappedRequest$$anonfun$loadAndRunReq$1.apply(IMain.scala:645)
    at scala.tools.nsc.interpreter.IMain$WrappedRequest$$anonfun$loadAndRunReq$1.apply(IMain.scala:644)
    at scala.reflect.internal.util.ScalaClassLoader$class.asContext(ScalaClassLoader.scala:31)
    at scala.reflect.internal.util.AbstractFileClassLoader.asContext(AbstractFileClassLoader.scala:19)
    at scala.tools.nsc.interpreter.IMain$WrappedRequest.loadAndRunReq(IMain.scala:644)
    at scala.tools.nsc.interpreter.IMain.interpret(IMain.scala:576)
    at scala.tools.nsc.interpreter.IMain.interpret(IMain.scala:572)
    at com.databricks.backend.daemon.driver.DriverILoop.execute(DriverILoop.scala:215)
    at com.databricks.backend.daemon.driver.ScalaDriverLocal$$anonfun$repl$1.apply$mcV$sp(ScalaDriverLocal.scala:197)
    at com.databricks.backend.daemon.driver.ScalaDriverLocal$$anonfun$repl$1.apply(ScalaDriverLocal.scala:197)
    at com.databricks.backend.daemon.driver.ScalaDriverLocal$$anonfun$repl$1.apply(ScalaDriverLocal.scala:197)
    at com.databricks.backend.daemon.driver.DriverLocal$TrapExitInternal$.trapExit(DriverLocal.scala:679)
    at com.databricks.backend.daemon.driver.DriverLocal$TrapExit$.apply(DriverLocal.scala:632)
    at com.databricks.backend.daemon.driver.ScalaDriverLocal.repl(ScalaDriverLocal.scala:197)
    at com.databricks.backend.daemon.driver.DriverLocal$$anonfun$execute$8.apply(DriverLocal.scala:368)
    at com.databricks.backend.daemon.driver.DriverLocal$$anonfun$execute$8.apply(DriverLocal.scala:345)
    at com.databricks.logging.UsageLogging$$anonfun$withAttributionContext$1.apply(UsageLogging.scala:238)
    at scala.util.DynamicVariable.withValue(DynamicVariable.scala:58)
    at com.databricks.logging.UsageLogging$class.withAttributionContext(UsageLogging.scala:233)
    at com.databricks.backend.daemon.driver.DriverLocal.withAttributionContext(DriverLocal.scala:48)
    at com.databricks.logging.UsageLogging$class.withAttributionTags(UsageLogging.scala:271)
    at com.databricks.backend.daemon.driver.DriverLocal.withAttributionTags(DriverLocal.scala:48)
    at com.databricks.backend.daemon.driver.DriverLocal.execute(DriverLocal.scala:345)
    at com.databricks.backend.daemon.driver.DriverWrapper$$anonfun$tryExecutingCommand$2.apply(DriverWrapper.scala:644)
    at com.databricks.backend.daemon.driver.DriverWrapper$$anonfun$tryExecutingCommand$2.apply(DriverWrapper.scala:644)
    at scala.util.Try$.apply(Try.scala:192)
    at com.databricks.backend.daemon.driver.DriverWrapper.tryExecutingCommand(DriverWrapper.scala:639)
    at com.databricks.backend.daemon.driver.DriverWrapper.getCommandOutputAndError(DriverWrapper.scala:485)
    at com.databricks.backend.daemon.driver.DriverWrapper.executeCommand(DriverWrapper.scala:597)
    at com.databricks.backend.daemon.driver.DriverWrapper.runInnerLoop(DriverWrapper.scala:390)
    at com.databricks.backend.daemon.driver.DriverWrapper.runInner(DriverWrapper.scala:337)
    at com.databricks.backend.daemon.driver.DriverWrapper.run(DriverWrapper.scala:219)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
```

Comment: My endpoint is running on a kubernetes cluster in google cloud, I think that is the actual problem, because I have tried another url and I don't get the error.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I couldn't ping point the cause of the problem but I found a workaround which is not to use OkHttp, replacing the code that makes a request with this worked.

```
HttpResponse<String> response = Unirest.get("<some_url>")
                .header("cache-control", "no-cache")
                .asString();
```

Answer (score 0):

This is because of secure cipher suites incompatibility:

**Databricks** is choosing efficient cipher suites

**OkHttp** - modern secure cipher suites

To make it work, you can analyze the API with https://www.ssllabs.com/ssltest/

There would be a section with Cipher Suites supported by the API, you have to explicitly set them like this (for my situation CBC_SHA256 was the deal):

```
ConnectionSpec spec = new ConnectionSpec.Builder(ConnectionSpec.MODERN_TLS)
    .tlsVersions(TlsVersion.TLS_1_2)
    .cipherSuites(
        CipherSuite.TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_AES_128_GCM_SHA256,
        CipherSuite.TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA256,
        CipherSuite.TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA384
    )
    .build();

OkHttpClient client = new OkHttpClient.Builder()
    .connectionSpecs(Collections.singletonList(spec))
    .build();
```

https://square.github.io/okhttp/https/

I've found a lot of information and description here:
https://github.com/square/okhttp/issues/6138